# Find the algorithm behind this repeating number sequence

Tags: pattern, number-sequence

During a garage sale I saw a strange old electronic device (not really, it's just flavor story). It had a battery slot, a button and a row of seven-segment displays - though from all except the two last digits the magic smoke had clearly escaped. Curious, I bought it for a dollar, took it home and put in a battery. Right away a **single-digit number** showed on the display (**not a 7**). I pressed the button, and the number changed. Trying it a few more times, I noticed a pattern to the numbers: it always went

```
97, 65, 85,    67, 15, 35,
37, 65, 85,    07, 15, 35,
77, 65, 85,    47, 15, 35,
17, 65, 85,    87, 15, 35,
57, 65, 85,    27, 15, 35.
```

After a while I got bored, so I threw the device away. However, it has been nagging at me what rule might be underlying the pattern of this number sequence. Maybe you know?

Comment: The pattern among each column seems somewhat straightforward, but the transition from 85 to 67 is boggling. Following my theory, I would have expected it to cycle back to 97.

Comment: Note that only the display is modulo 100, the internal calculation considers all digits. The repeating pattern consists of all 30 numbers in sequence. The line breaks making the columns are only to show that there are sub-patterns (7-5-5 in the single digits, 6-8-1-3 in the tens of the numbers ending in 5, 9-6-3-0-7-4-1-8-5-2 in the tens of the numbers ending in 7).

Comment: The pattern I'm noticing is as such: 97+65+85=2**3**0+17; 37+65+85=1**7**0+17... Summing the tens digits yields a tens digit that is used in the next term.

Comment: Another way of looking at it is ((x+y+z)%100)-10, where % is a modulus operation.

Comment: @Bulldogg6404 Don't you mean $(x+y+z-10)\%100$? Subtracting $10$ after the modulo operation gives $-3$ on the last one instead of starting over at $97$.  Note that your $(x+y+z-10)\%100$ is the same as $x_{n+6} = (x_{n} + 40)\%100$. Similarly you can say $x_{n+3} = (x_n - 30)\%100$ (of course, both still only for $n$ where $x_n\%10=7$). If one knows the solution one can easily derive why this holds, but I don't know whether the reverse is true...

Comment: I'm guessing it's powers of some number, personally.

Comment: Given the many old and strange calculating devices found on this site, maybe there really is a garage sale.

Comment: Looking at the 1st and 4th columns, you get 97, 67, 37, 07, 77, ...... (basically subtraction of 30). The 2nd, 3rd, 5th and 6th columns just have the same number. What's the puzzle in this?

Comment: @ghosts_in_the_code  I think the puzzle is to figure out a function that transforms each number into the next 97 -> 65 -> 85 -> 67, etc.

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain That is still easy, unless you are banning the conditional operator (?).

Comment: Edit:  I think the puzzle is to figure out a **generic** function that transforms each number into the next.

Comment: All the specific numbers shown follow the rule $a_n=(a_{n-3}\cdot 11)\;\%\;100$. That doesn't explain the single-digit starting number, though.

Comment: @SebastianReichelt that's only the pattern $a_n \rightarrow a_{n+3}$, but there also is one $a_n \rightarrow a_{n+1}$ (which isn't as simple, but uses no conditional operator - unless you count $\min$ to be one).

Comment: How many seven segments are there? Two? Which segments had it's 'smoke' escaped? Do you mean that a portion of the seven segments' isn't working? I believe the key is there and that once you assume that the display is partially broken, the underlying computation becomes apparent. Otherwise, I'd say the pattern only considers the first number and is substracting 3 modulus 10 and appending digits (which depend on wether the number is odd or even).

Comment: @quimnuss I believe there are a certain amount of seven-segment displays, yet only the last two work. The first $N$ places of the numbers are still included in the computation, but it only shows the last 2 digits.

Answer (score 3):

In the hope of being told what the real answer is supposed to be, here is a strange rule that produces the correct numbers (using "min", since you mentioned it):

$a_0 = 9$

$a_{n+1} = \min((a_n \cdot 100)\,\%\,1000000 + (\lfloor a_n / 10000 \rfloor \cdot 11)\,\%\,100, 976585)$

$a_5$ is the first item that belongs to the repeating sequence, but it is not the beginning of that sequence. The sequence starts over for the first time at $a_{33}$.

Comment: While not the one I intended, it does fit the pattern offered. I'll wait if anyone comes up with something better, though.

Answer (score 1):

So, this probably doesn't have much of anything to do with anything, but...

Treat this not as six columns but as three:

```
97, 65, 85,    
37, 65, 85,    
77, 65, 85,    
17, 65, 85,    
57, 65, 85,
```

---

```
67, 15, 35,    
07, 15, 35,
47, 15, 35,
87, 15, 35,
27, 15, 35.
```

The first column loops -60,+40 while the second and third columns are identical down. `57` would go down to `-3`. Since there are only seven segment displays, there is no easy way to show a negative with two places.

I can't quite resolve a good reason for the two extra columns to drop down. Together they lose `100`, assuming this is a base 10 system. But why assume that? Perhaps the **single digit number** that flashed was the base for this counter...

Answer (score 1):

> Take just the first columns from both blocks. To find the next single digit, add 7 to the current digit and consider only the the digit corresponding to the unit. The pattern starts with the digit 9 on the 1st line on the 1st block: • 9 + 7 = 16 => 6 on the 2nd block     • 6 + 7 = 13 => 3 on the 1st block     • 3 + 7 = 10 => 0 on the 2nd block     • etc...

Answer (score 1):

Simple algorithm, just needs formatting to pad number with a zero

```
Cstart=97

C=Cstart

I=1


While I==1 or C <> Cstart

   Print (C)

   Print (“,65,85,     “)

   C=C-30

   If C<0

     C=100-C

   Print (c)

   Print (“,15,35\n”)

   C=C-30

   If C<100

      C=C-30

   I++
```

Answer (score 1):

I can understand part of what's happening.

It has three groups of digits.  We are seeing the second and third groups.

## Third Group

The third group is counting:

```
50, 65, 85, 00, 15, 35,
50, 65, 85, 00, 15, 35,
50, 65, 85, 00, 15, 35,
```

This is a fraction counting by $1\over6$, rounded to the nearest 0.05.  This part is displayed except when the value is 00 or 50.

## Second Group

This is counting:

```
97, 87, 77, 67, 57, 47,
37, 27, 17, 07, 97, 87,
77, 67, 57, 47, 37, 27,
```

I don't know what the 7 represents, but the tens digit decrementing is obvious.  This value is displayed in the right two positions when the third group is 00 or 50, and displayed in the next two positions over otherwise.  Of course, since those positions are damaged, we don't see them.

## First Group

We don't know what the first group is.  It would be visible on the left (damaged) positions when the third group is 00 or 50.  I suspect it is related to the initial displayed single digit.

## What is it?

I suspect this is a scoring or timing device for a sports activity of some sort.  I have no idea what sport.  Though I find the rounding reminiscent of tennis's scoring:

```
love, 15, 30, 40, game.
```

## Further Thoughts

Cost of the seven segment display was a concern, or they wouldn't have done the shifting of the digits.  I suspect the device was from the 1970s or maybe 1980s.  It was almost certainly mass produced, as the cost wouldn't have been a concern for a one shot device.  The controller wouldn't be a microprocessor, they were too pricy in that era.